# Differentiation in DFT

Tags: analysis, numerical-methods

Let's consider some function $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ vanishing outside of some interval $(0,L)$. Then I can approximate the Fourier transform $\hat f$ by
$$ \hat f (k) = \int_{\mathbb R} e^{-i k x} f(x) \mathrm d x = \int_0^L e^{-i k x} f(x) \mathrm d x \approx \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{-i k x_j} f(x_j) \Delta x = \Delta x \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{-i k j \Delta x} f_j, $$
where $\Delta x = \frac L N$ and $x_j = j \Delta x$. This permits the interpretation of the DFT $\hat f_l = \sum_{j=0}^{N-1} e^{-i 2 \pi lj/N} f_j$ as an approximation for the Fourier transform (except normalization) where the index $l$ belongs to the momentum/frequency $\frac{2 \pi l}{\Delta x N}$. For this approximation it is obvious that $\hat f(k + \frac{2 \pi}{\Delta x}) = \hat f(k)$ (or $\hat f_{l+N} = \hat f_l$).

As we know the Fourier transform of $f'$ is $\widehat {(f')}(k) = - ik\hat f (k)$ which is clearly no more periodic. By which reason do I have to use momenta/frequencies symmetrically distributed around 0? (Do I have to do that?)

Comment: I don't understand the question very well. What I can say is that, when you approximate the continuous Fourier transform with the DFT, you are in fact discretizing the signal $f$ (i.e. approximating $f$ with the vector $(f(x_j)\,:\,j=0...N-1)$) and then considering the Fourier transform of this vector seen as a function in $L^2(\mathbb{Z}/N\mathbb{Z})$. The derivative clearly does not fit well in this discretization process.

Comment: @GiuseppeNegro: I want to numerically compute $\widehat {(f')} (k) = - i k \hat f(k)$. When approximating by using the DFT I would go for $\widehat {(f')}_l = - i \frac{2 \pi l}{\Delta x N} \hat f_l$ but I could also say (which seems to be the correct way)
$$ \widehat {(f')}_l = \begin{cases} - i \frac{2 \pi l}{\Delta x N} \hat f_l & 0 \le l \lt N/2 \\
- i \frac{2 \pi (l-N)}{\Delta x N} \hat f_l & N/2 \le l \lt N
\end{cases}$$
which differs from the previous.

Sorry, I'm currently quite a bit confused about this ;-)